# JSONata: Escape \ to \\

Tags: jsonata

I have a query which matches user's regex patterns to user's inputs - both will come in as strings. This is my basic setup: https://try.jsonata.org/5-Z2739H9

Unfortunately it looks like I need to escape my usual regex \ to JSONata's $eval expected \, so from something like "\b[0-9]{3}\b" to "\b[0-9]{3}\b".

The usual suspects don't seem to work:

`$replace("\b[0-9]{3}\b", "\", "\\")`
`$replace("\b[0-9]{3}\b", "\\", "\\\\")`

It works if I escape a specific regex character like `\b` (https://try.jsonata.org/A6xDOrYl5) but I'd like to generalize and spare myself a bunch of IF/ELSE cases if I can.

Any idea how to properly escape 's? Any ideas (or hints why this is a bad idea) are much appreciated :)